# C++ - Measure live audio input percentage

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

I want to return the value (int) of the live volume level from Mic (Kind of like in windows) and I'm starting with the backend, I wrote the call back and the startCapture but I get values like this as the volume: 1438564139,-1573175544, please help find the problem.
I start `Pa_OpenStream` with 1 channel, on SAMPLE_44100_HZ and 256 on framesPerBuffer
My callback function:

```
        static double globalVolumePercentage = 0.0;
        int AudioCapturerPortAudio::audioVolumeAnalyzerCallback(const void* inputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags)
    {
        try
        {
            const double *input = static_cast<const double*>(inputBuffer);
        double volumeNorm = 0.0;

        // Calculate the input level as the average absolute amplitude of the samples
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; ++i) {
            volumeNorm  += static_cast<double>(input[i]) * static_cast<double>(input[i]);
        }
        volumeNorm = std::sqrt(volumeNorm) * 10.0;

        globalVolumePercentage = volumeNorm/100;
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("AudioCapturerPortAudio audioVolumeAnalyzerCallback failed to analyze audio, exception: %s", ex.what());
    }
    return paContinue;
}
```

[image: examlple of end result]